# How to display action text in a listbox and not in a textarea in installshield basic msi project?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I am working on basic msi project. I want to display all actiontexts in a list.
By default, it is subscribed by a text area....

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Windows Installer. Only a static text control can subscribe to action text.

Comment: But do you have any idea, how can i show chechmark list in setup progress dialog...??

Comment: This is not supported by Windows Installer. It can be done only with an external UI.